# How do I create a new dataframe based on row values of multiple columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, etl

I have multiple columns that contained only 0s or 1s.

| Apple | Orange | Pear |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

I would like to count  and input the number of 0s (in "Wrong" column) and 1s (in "Correct" column) of each column in the new dataframe, and total them up into a table that looks like the following.

| Fruit | Correct | Wrong |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 2 | 1 |
| Orange | 1 | 2 |
| Pear | 2 | 1 |

I tried a blend of `value_counts()`, `groupby()`,  and `pandas.pivot_table`, but got stuck with the manipulation of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).rename(index={0:'Wrong', 1:'Correct'}).T
```

Use `pd.DataFrame.apply` to "apply" `pd.Series.value_counts` to each column of the dataframe, then `rename` the index values using a dictionary for 0 and 1 to Wrong and Correct.  Lastly, use `T` to transpose the dataframe.

Output:

```
        Wrong  Correct
Apple       1        2
Orange      2        1
Pear        1        2
```

And, you can add `.rename_axis('Fruit').reset_index()` to get:

```
    Fruit  Wrong  Correct
0   Apple      1        2
1  Orange      2        1
2    Pear      1        2
```

Comment: I believe this is the answer. May I suggest `fillna(0)` as a small improvement?

Comment: I think using `value_counts` in a loop is overkill here. You don't need to count both 0/1, just count 1s and the number of 0s will be linked ;)

Comment: I think using `value_counts` may be overkill for experts, but quite helpful for noobs like me to unpack the process with greater clarity.

Comment: @Beavis of course, but learning is also about being aware of those things. Be lazy, only compute what's really needed ;)

Comment: I actually have a different thought that most on this topic.  I love pandas because there are many ways to get to an answer.  I opine that sometimes you want to get the correct answer fastest for you.  This "fastest for you way" may not be more computationally cheaper, but in real world time you can get the answer faster.  Later, if you need to run this code repeatedly, then you can look for more optimal solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to compute both Correct and Wrong simultaneously. One number is determined once you know the other.

Simply count ([`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)) the correct and post-process:

```
out = (df.sum()
   .rename_axis('Fruit')
   .reset_index(name='Correct')
   .assign(Wrong=lambda d: len(df)-d['Correct'])
 )
```

Output:

```
    Fruit  Correct  Wrong
0   Apple        2      1
1  Orange        1      2
2    Pear        2      1
```

Comment: can you help unpack your code one line at a time to say what the code does? After looking at it for an hour, I still don't quite understand what each line is doing. When you approach a problem like the one I listed, how to you think about it?

Comment: @Beavis comment all lines and uncomment them one by one to see the progression. 1- `sum` the 1s which gives a Series, 2- rename the index, 3- convert to DataFrame with "correct" as column name for the values. 4- create a new column from "correct" with the difference to the original number of rows (this gives the count of 0s)

Answer (score 2):

if your dataframe is :

```
data = {
    "Apple": [1, 0, 1],
    "Orange": [0, 0, 1],
    "Pear": [1, 1, 0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

you can do:

```
value_counts = df.apply(lambda col: col.value_counts()).T

counts = value_counts.rename(columns={1: "Correct", 0: "Wrong"})
counts = counts.reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "Fruit"})
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Just a thought from the outside. We can apply `pd.Series.value_counts` as far as its first parameter is self. IMO, when we can apply some inner pandas or numpy function rather than lambda, the internal mechanism can run faster. Also, we have to decide in advance to fill in nan values in corner cases, no?

Comment: The column with row values apple, orange, and pear is unnamed. How do you refer to this specific column / rename this column?

Answer (score 1):

The code below first iterates through the columns (`.apply(..., axis=0)`), returning a list of `[num. of 0, num of 1]` per column. The rows and columns of that new dataframe are swapped round (`.T`) to get the fruit names as rows, and finally the columns are renamed to 'correct' and 'wrong'.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'apple': [1, 0, 1], 'orange': [0, 0, 1], 'pear': [1, 1, 0]})

new_df = df.apply(
    lambda x: [ (x==0).sum(), (x==1).sum()],
    axis=0
).T.rename(columns={1: 'correct', 0: 'wrong'})
```

Comment: The column with row values apple, orange, and pear is unnamed. How do you refer to this specific column / rename this column?

Comment: In this case it is actually the index (not a regular column). If you want a name for the index, you can do: `new_df.index.name="Fruits"`. If you also want to turn it into a regular column, then also run this line afterwards: `new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)`.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
print(
    pd.concat([df.sum(), (df == 0).sum()], axis=1)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={0: "Correct", 1: "Wrong", "index": "Fruit"})
)
```

Prints:

```
    Fruit  Correct  Wrong
0   Apple        2      1
1  Orange        1      2
2    Pear        2      1
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

After some thought, I think it's better to just apply `value_counts` along each column:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).fillna(0).T
```

Of course, we can `reset_index` at the end. But isn't it good to keep fruits as index?

---

#### Previous answer

In general case, I'd use this way:

```
interpretation = {0:'Wrong', 1:'Correct'}   

(
    df
    .rename_axis(columns='Fruit')
    .stack()
    .groupby(level=-1)               # group by fruits
    .value_counts()     
    .unstack(fill_value=0)           # move unique values to columns
    .rename(columns=interpretation)
    .reset_index()
)
```

E.g. we can modify data and their interpretation as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Apple': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1},
    'Orange': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1},
    'Pear': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0},
    'Bananas': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
    'Mango': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0},
    'Avocado': {0: 0.5, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0}}
)
interpretation = {0:'Wrong', 1:'Correct', .5: 'Uncertain'}
```

and obtain the answer:

```
     Fruit  Wrong  Uncertain  Correct
0    Apple      1          0        2
1  Avocado      2          1        0
2  Bananas      0          0        3
3    Mango      3          0        0
4   Orange      2          0        1
5     Pear      1          0        2
```

Comment: Your point about including a `fillna(0)` option is very thoughtful and I used it in my analysis.